# How to pass a generic type into an object property callback function

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to pass a generic type to a callback lambda function

```
interface Interface { 
   onChange: <T = string>(val: T) => void 
}

const handleOnChange = (val: MY_ENUM) => {...}

const myConfig: Interface[] = [{
    onChange: <MY_ENUM>(val) => handleOnChange(val);
}]
```

**the code above doesn't work.**

Comment: Try [this](https://tsplay.dev/w16a2N) exmaple

Comment: I don't know why it is mandatory to put a comma after you provide a generic.

Comment: This is because TS expect jsx syntax. With comma, TS is aware that you are writing generics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
interface Interface {
  onChange: <T = string>(val: T) => void
}

const handleOnChange = <T,>(val: T) => { }

const myConfig: Interface[] = [{
  onChange: handleOnChange
}]
```

**You had to add a COMMA at the beginning of your config function when passing the generic**

Thanks to,
@captain-yossarian

Comment: you don't have to use comma, a simple `T extends any` will also work.

Comment: Btw, take a look on [this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47607) PR, it will be possible to write `onChange: handleOnChange<number>`